# Cant load ViewController when add local notification scripts to "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions"

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

after adding local notification script in "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" it said

> [1627:60b] Application windows are expected to have a root view
>   controller at the end of application launch

and this is the code

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{
mainStoryboard = nil;
if (IS_IPHONE_5) {
    mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainIPhone5" bundle:nil];
}
else {
    mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainIPhone" bundle:nil];
}
UILocalNotification *localNotification = launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
if (localNotification) {
    SelectedTask = [localNotification.userInfo objectForKey:@"FullTaskName"];
    TaskViewController *TaskViewControllerVar;
    TaskViewControllerVar = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TaskViewController"];
    TaskViewControllerVar.SelectedTask = SelectedTask;
    self.window.rootViewController = TaskViewControllerVar;
    NSLog(@"1");
}else{
    RecordingViewController *RecordingViewControllerVar;
    RecordingViewControllerVar = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RecordingViewController"];
    self.window.rootViewController = RecordingViewControllerVar;
    NSLog(@"2");
}
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

}

Comment: are you running on iphone 5?

Comment: i have two storyboard one for iPhone4 and one for iPhone5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove this line

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
```

you also need to add the views. Like this:

```
self.window.rootViewController = TaskViewControllerVar;
[self.window addSubview:TaskViewControllerVar.view];
```

and

```
self.window.rootViewController = RecordingViewControllerVar;
[self.window addSubview:RecordingViewControllerVar.view];
```